# Is there a way to create custom warning in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I know that the obvious answer is "pay attention" but because I am constantly switching between Java and Javascript, I'm endlessly forgetting that == doesn't work for string comparison on the Java side of things.  Is there any way to get Eclipse to warn me that I'm probably not doing what I want to be doing when it sees me comparing two strings with `==` rather than using the equals() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many static code analyzer available which does such type of things.
Few of them are:

1. [checkStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)
2. [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
3. [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)
4. [findBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

They have many in-built rules and you can configure them in eclipse also. So as and when, you type and save, these tools would also show warnings just like in-built eclipse warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Eclipse JSHint plugin](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/), which can warn if you mistakenly use `==` instead of `===` in Javascript.

Comment: wait... based on that image, it looks like it offers me warnings on the javascript side of things, rather than Java.  I'm specifically looking for a way to have the Java side of things detect the `==` when used for String comparison. Does it tack that in as well, or is this a JS helper only?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: No. I misread your question; I thought you wanted JS warnings for not using `===`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended just using FindBugs, it's the best free code review program I've used..

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to take a look at APT (if you are using jdk 1.5, 1.6) or processor (if jdk 1.7). You can integrate your custom code into your eclipse and get the behavior very easily you want.