# Extend Eclipse Error / Warning mechanism to include other code hints

Tags: java, eclipse, static-analysis

We are developing some automated tasks in Java in Eclipse. We are using our in-house Framework for that. In this framework we have certain `getButton().press()` and `getButton().release()`

Personally I forget a lot of the times to release a pressed button. Is there a way to tell eclipse or even the compiler to throw an error or at least a warning if a press statement is not followed by matching release? The release statements don't have to follow the press statement immediately.

Could you please also suggests tags for this question, I am not sure how what tags would be appropriate.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372036/is-there-a-way-to-create-custom-warning-in-eclipse) may help

Comment: is it possible to extend any of these proposed static code analysis tools?

Comment: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/extending.html and sonarqube seems also extensible http://www.sonarqube.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors/warnings shown in Eclipse are called **problem markers**. You can add **problem marker** as a tag.

[Here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_problem_markers_for_my_compiler%3F) is how the problem markers are implemented in Eclipse:

- Right before compiling the resource, they remove all problem markers from the resource:

  ```
  void compileResource(IResource resource) {
      resource.deleteMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, Resource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
      doCompileResource(resource);
  }
  ```
- During compilation, errors are attached to the resource as follows:

  ```
  void reportError(IResource resource, int line, String msg) {
     IMarker m = resource.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
     m.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);
     m.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, msg);
     m.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
     m.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
  }
  ```
- Markers can be created in this way:

  ```
  IMarker marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.TASK);
  ```
- And Markers can be deleted in this way:

  ```
  try {
      marker.delete();
  } catch (CoreException e) {
      // Something went wrong
  }
  ```

More you can find in [Eclipse F&Q](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_problem_markers_for_my_compiler%3F) and [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_markers.htm).

Also, [this article](http://cubussapiens.hu/2010/11/markers-and-annotations-in-eclipse-for-error-feedback/) may be useful too.